# Anidar una tercera opción en echo isset

Tags: php, pdo, formularios

Como puedo meter en este form una función más: Tengo actualizar y registrar y quisiera poner una más por ejemplo update:

```
<form class="contacto" id="form1" action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">                    
</form>
```

por ejemplo si pongo:

```
<form class="contacto" id="form1" action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar' :'update'; ?>" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
```

Así no funciona

Comment: No entiendo la diferencia entre actualizar y update. Por otro lado, los operadores ternarios ( condicion?cumple condicion:no cumple condicion) son sentencias abreviadas de IF, por lo que no puedes poner una tercera opción como en: ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar' :'update'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

en realidad tu función no agrega mas funciones es un simple if

```
<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar';?>
```

seria como

```
if (isset($obj_categoria)){
         actualizar();
}else{
         registrar();
}
```

si deseas algo mas complejo necesitarías llamar un código que maneje el flujo, algo como

```
<?php
    if (isset($obj_categoria)){
             'actualizar'
    }else if (otra_condicion){
             'registrar'
    }else{
             'upgrade'
    }
?>
```

obviamente ante esta complejidad ya no es muy útil usar la forma:

```
 condicion?true:false
```

asi que utiliza la forma larga

```
if(condicion1){
   opcion1; //condicion1, true
}else if(condicion2){
   opcion2; //condicion1, flase, condicion2, true
}else{
   opcion3; //condicion1, flase, condicion2, false
}
```

Comment: y no habría ninguna manera de meter una 3 condición?

Comment: cuando quieres que se ejecute el primero?, cuando quieres que se ejecute el 2do? y cuando el tercero?... seria un simple if anidado

Comment: Resumen: Son 3 botones, registrar,editar, y el tercero es que recoja los datos como el de editar pero que lo meta como un nuevo registro.  Entonces debería ser registrar : editar : upgrade

Comment: lo que se lee en tu codigo es, cuando existe obj_categoria, actualizar la informacion, de lo contrario, insertar informacion nueva (registrar).

aqui no hay una tercera ocion, existe obj_categoria o no existe.

cuando quieres que se ejecute upgrade,  cuando exista $onj_categoria y ($otra_condicion)

Comment: y no habría ninguna manera de meter una opción más?

Comment: si, actualice la respuesta para explicar esto...

Comment: action="?action=<?php if($obj_categoria){
   'actualizar'; //condicion1, true
}else if($obj_categoria){
   'registrar'; //condicion1, flase, condicion2, true
}else{
   'upgrade'; //condicion1, flase, condicion2, false
}?>"      No logro hacer que me funcione se me queda la pag en blanco

Comment: copiando y pegando el código no  va a funcionar, primero por que pretende ser solo un ejemplo no código funcional; segundo por que tienes que adaptarlo al resto de tu código, intenta entender, digierelo y luego adaptarlo a tu situación.

Answer (score 0):

Tu función es un if de una sola línea:

```
condicion ? 'si true se devuelve esto' : 'si false se devuelve esto otro';
```

Lo indicado por Jorge Arturo Juarez es correcto, pero se puede utilizar perfectamente un if de una línea dentro de otro sin mayor problema que la legibilidad que tendrá después el código para ser entendido.

Por ejemplo:

```
condicion1 ? 'condicion1 es true' : (condicion2 ? 'condicion 1 es false pero condicion2 es true' : 'condicion1 es false, pero condicion2 es false';)
```

> En este caso los paréntesis son obligatorios, porque sino el segundo ? utiliza todo lo anterior como condición.